# Triggering External ICommands/Functions from inside a ListItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, icommand

I'm wondering what the best method is for triggering external functions (or commands) from within a inner list item.

For example, I have a `FooManager` object which contains an ObservableCollection of `Foo` objects called `MyFoos`. FooManager also has a function called `ProcessFoo(Foo foo)`.

```
<StackPanel DataContext="FooManager">
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyFoos}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <Button Content="Do Something"
                            Command="{Binding Path=SomeFooCommand} />
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

How do I trigger the ProcessFoo(Foo foo) function (and passing the 'clicked' Foo) by clicking the "Do Something" button?

I realise I could use code-behind to do this, but I'm wondering what the cleanest MVVM approach is. Should the ViewModel for Foo contain a reference to it's FooManager, or is it bad practice for ViewModels to reference each other?

Comment: Bind to the ListView's DataContext: `Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SomeFooCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"`

Comment: In that case, would passing the Foo itself as a CommandParameter be correct?

Comment: Correct in which sense? If the command needs to get access to the current item, you'd certainly pass the current Foo instance as command parameter.

Comment: Sorry - 'correct' as in 'best practice'. Thanks for you help @Clemens !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Clemens. In the FooManager class, add a command which takes a Foo VM as a parameter. The Button in the DataTemplate can then trigger this by using a `RelativeSource` in the binding, and passing itself (an empty `{Binding}`) as parameter.

```
<StackPanel DataContext="FooManager">
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyFoos}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <Button Content="Do Something"
                            Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ProcessFoo, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncenstorType=ListView}}
                            CommandParameter={Binding} />
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score -1):

I use Prism's DelegateCommand, I think this is the easiest way to bind to commands. It is pretty versatile with many other command options. If you have visual studio go to Tools > NuGet Package manager > Mange packages, in Browse search Prism and install Prism.Core. Or you can create your own DelegateCommand implementing ICommand interface. Another option for delegatecommand is at the bottom of this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36545/WPF-MVVM-Model-View-View-Model-Simplified, which uses wpf mvvm toolkit. Here is an implementation with prism:

view.xaml:

```
<Button Command="{Binding FooCommand}" />
```

viewmodel.cs:

```
  public DelegateCommand FooCommand { get; private set; }
  FooCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnFoo, CanFoo);
  private void OnFoo()
  {
     ProcessFoo(ListViewName.SelectedItems);
  }
  private bool CanFoo()
  {
     return someBooleanFunc();
  }
```

You would want to move the "FooCommand = new ..." to the ViewModel constructor.

Comment: This does look like a good implementation of MVVM. However it doesn't solve my problem of binding to Commands outside of a control's Data Context

Comment: I didn't really see that in your question. You asked for the cleanest MVVM approach and that's what this is. I'm not sure if unrestricted access to commands would be a "clean" MVVM approach. I updated my answer, changed Start() to your ProcessFoo() method, you can add a Name to the List control and pass in the SelectedItems.